# Sympy fails to solve a linear system of ODEs

Tags: python, sympy

I have recently started to use sympy to do symbolic computations with python. Now, I am working with ODEs and yesterday I was trying to solve the very simpe initial value problem:

```
    y1'   =    y1 + 2 y2,
    y2'   = -2 y1 +   y2 + 2 exp(t),
```

with the initial conditions

```
    y1(0) =  y2(0) = 1
```

The python code I have written is the following:

```
>>> import sympy as sy    
>>> t=sy.symbols('t')
>>> y1=sy.Function('y1')   
>>> y2=sy.Function('y2')
>>> eqs=(sy.Eq(y1(t).diff(t),y1(t)+2*y2(t)), sy.Eq(y2(t).diff(t),-2*y1(t)+y2(t)+2*sy.exp(t))) 
>>> s=sy.dsolve(eqs)        # General solution
>>> s
[y1(t) == 2*(C1*sin(2*t) + C2*cos(2*t))*exp(t),
 y2(t) == (2*C1*cos(2*t) - 2*C2*sin(2*t))*exp(t)]
>>> y1g=s[0].args[1]
>>> y2g=s[1].args[1]
>>> # Find C1 and C2 so that the initial condition is satisfied
>>> sol=sy.solve([y1g.subs(t,0)-1,y2g.subs(t,0)-1])
>>> sol
{C1: 1/2, C2: 1/2}
>>> y1=y1g.subs(sol)
>>> y2=y2g.subs(sol)
>>> [y1,y2]
[2*(sin(2*t)/2 + cos(2*t)/2)*exp(t), (-sin(2*t) + cos(2*t))*exp(t)]
```

But the solution is wrong!! Did I make a mistake or this is a sympy bug?

Comment: What should the solution be? If it's wrong, report it at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new.

Comment: Thanks, I have reported it. I hope a fix can be found soon. It seems that the sympy module to solve ODEs is not very reliable at the moment, at least regarding systems of ODEs.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: This is not an answer but a comment needing badly to be clearly formatted

I copied the 1st part of your code in a file

```
% cat sy.py
import sympy as sy    
t=sy.symbols('t')
y1=sy.Function('y1')   
y2=sy.Function('y2')
eqs=(sy.Eq(y1(t).diff(t),y1(t)+2*y2(t)), sy.Eq(y2(t).diff(t),-2*y1(t)+y2(t)+2*sy.exp(t))) 
s=sy.dsolve(eqs)
%
```

and later I run python on it

```
% python2.7 sy.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sy.py", line 6, in <module>
    s=sy.dsolve(eqs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/ode.py", line 525, in dsolve
    x0=x0, n=n, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/deutils.py", line 174, in _desolve
    eq, func = _preprocess(eq, func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/deutils.py", line 72, in _preprocess
    derivs = expr.atoms(Derivative)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'atoms'
%
```

There's a discrepancy between what you said you've got and what I get. and maybe it's my fault.

Comment: I forgot to say that I use python 3.3.2, sorry.

Comment: If the code works in python3 and doesn't work in python2 it is a bug of `sympy`. Fortunately it's not a problem for the OP.  As Debian testing has no `sympy` package for python3 I have to resign

Comment: Anyway, I have just tested the code with python 2.7.5 and sympy 0.7.3 under fedora 19 x64 and it works flawlessly

Comment: I have run into a similar issue as found by @gboffi, since this is currently the top Google result I'll post the solution here (not sure if that is acceptable?). This problem is [an open issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8012), but can easily be fixed by updating sympy to `=>0.7.6`.